# Real Analysis. Dense Sets. Unsure if Statement is True

Tags: real-analysis

I'm asked to prove the following theorem. However, I think it is incorrect to begin with. Could anyone double check me. If you know it's true, can you prove it?

> Prove that if $S$ is a dense subset of $M$ and $M \setminus S$ is open, then $S = M$.

Thanks

Comment: What types of sets are these?  Topological spaces?  Metric spaces?  Subsets of $\mathbb{R}$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is rather general-topology question than real-analysis. $S$ is dense if and only if it intersects every nonempty open set, clearly if $M \setminus S$ is open then $ (M \setminus S) \cap S = \emptyset \Rightarrow S = M$.

Answer (score 2):

If $M \setminus S$ is open then $S$ is closed, so it is equal to its closure, and the closure of a dense set is everything.

Answer (score 1):

This is true (in any topological space): if $M \setminus S$ is open and non-empty (!) it must intersect $S$ (definition of dense), which cannot be. So it is empty and $M = S$.